# SIMD vectorization strategies for group-by operations on multiple, very large data arrays

Tags: c#, performance, x86, simd, intrinsics

I have to do a large number of aggregation operations, with the output grouped by some dimension (int/byte ID). I'm using C#, but hopefully I can still get good advice from the majority C++ crowd reading this :)

A simplified version is below:

```
        public static (double[], double[]) AggregateDataGroupBy(double[] data, double[] weight, byte[] dimension)
        {
            int numberOfValues = byte.MaxValue - byte.MinValue + 1;
            double[] totalValue = new double[numberOfValues];
            double[] totalWeight = new double[numberOfValues];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                byte index = dimension[i];
                totalValue[index] += data[i];
                totalWeight[index] += weight[i];
            }

            return (totalValue, totalWeight);
        }
```

SIMD vectorization gives a significant speed-up when no needing to group over the dimension. My first attempt to vectorise the operation was to grab the running totals for the dimensions of the 4 rows being processed, load the input vectors using a gather, do the aggregation functions and then scatter back. As scatter isn't part of AVX2, this last part is particularly slow.

```
        public static unsafe (double[], double[]) AggregateDataGather(double[] data, double[] weight, int[] dimension)
        {
            int numberOfValues = 256;
            double[] totalValue = new double[numberOfValues];
            double[] totalWeight = new double[numberOfValues];

            if (Avx2.IsSupported)
            {
                int vectorSize = 256 / 8 / sizeof(double);
                int i;
                fixed (double* ptr = data, ptr2 = weight, ptrValue = totalValue, ptrWeight = totalWeight)
                {
                    fixed (int* dimptr = dimension)
                    {
                        var accValue = stackalloc double[vectorSize];
                        var accWeight = stackalloc double[vectorSize];
                        for (i = 0; i <= data.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
                        {
                            Vector128<int> indices = Avx2.LoadVector128(dimptr + i);
                            var accVectorV = Avx2.GatherVector256(ptrValue, indices, 8);
                            var accVectorW = Avx2.GatherVector256(ptrWeight, indices, 8);
                            var v = Avx2.LoadVector256(ptr + i);
                            var w = Avx2.LoadVector256(ptr2 + i);
                            accVectorV = Avx2.Add(accVectorV, v);
                            accVectorW = Avx2.Add(accVectorW, w);

                            Avx2.Store(accValue, accVectorV);
                            Avx2.Store(accWeight, accVectorW);
                            for (int ii = 0; ii < vectorSize; ii++)
                            {
                                var index = dimptr[i + ii];
                                totalValue[index] = accValue[ii];
                                totalWeight[index] = accWeight[ii];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (Avx.IsSupported || Sse42.IsSupported)
            {
                // Do other stuff
            }

            return (totalValue, totalWeight);
        }
```

(Please excuse the change of dimension from byte to int - I tested both and both are slower)

The intrinsics version above runs *slower* than the naive algorithm on my Ryzen 3600. (268ms for 100m values, rather than 230ms)

Given that my data only changes after many aggregations (over hundreds/thousands of different dimensions), I find that my fastest implementation can be to store the data (value, weight) in a vector and do a naive group-by. This gives similar performance on the Ryzen, but is 10% faster on an older i7 (without AVX).

```
        public static Vector2[] AggregateData(Vector2[] data, byte[] dimension)
        {
            int numberOfValues = byte.MaxValue - byte.MinValue + 1;
            Vector2[] sum = new Vector2[numberOfValues];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sum[dimension[i]] += data[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }
```

I'd read some papers on histogram functions that simply count the number of occurences of each dimension. They got a close to perfect 8x speed up compared to naive approaches.

Have I missed something in my attempt to use AVX2 intrinsics? Am I always going to be faced with inefficient gather/scatter operations? Any comments/suggestions?

As a sub-case, are there strategies that will only work when the dimension size is small (processing 4 dimension values at a time)? E.g. loading the value into a vector with a single non-zero value, as follows, and optimising the number of rows being processed at a time to use all the cache memory.

```
Values (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
Indicies (1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3)
=> 
  <0, 11, 0, 0>
+ <12, 0, 0, 0>
+ <0, 0, 0, 13>
+ <0, 14, 0, 0>
+ <0, 0, 15, 0>
+ <16, 0, 0, 0>
+ <0, 0, 0, 17>
```

(This didn't appear to me a likely solution, due to inefficiency once the dimension size increases. So I haven't tried it yet, but I will if it's suggested as an efficient work-around.)

Comment: Histogram is a problematic use case for SIMD. You need scatter/gather and conflict detection instructions (added by AVX512CD), so you don't lose any updates if two elements in the same vector belong to the same bucket.

Comment: When using SIMD it is usually more efficient to use a [structure-of-arrays rather than array-of-structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA). I.e. Store X1, X2 ... Y1, Y2 instead of X1, Y1, X2, Y2. It might or might not be worth rewriting existing code, but I wanted to mention the alternative.

Comment: @ JonasH In giving the data[] and weight[] arrays separately, am I not following a structure-of-arrays models? Or were you referring ot the Vector2 option? The latter appeared to speed things-up by cheaply allowing for hardware aceleration. 

Yes, I prefer the SoA model too, as the number of data columns can change.

The code base doesn't exist yet (re-writing from scratch) I want to take advantage of existing and upcoming functionality. If this means sticking with naive until I have access to AVX512, then that's ok. But I don't want to bank on an efficient scatter that never arrives!

Comment: @EOF - yes, it's problematic and why I'm wondering if I'm tackling it the right way.

I also wonder if I should batch all my data into chunks that are ordered by the dimension. This would use a lot of processing nodes/memory, but would allow standard vectorisation approches for large contiguous blocks (remembering that there are many iterations, so the sort could be a good investment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, vectorization is hard for such aggregation use case. However, it does not mean SIMD is completely useless for your problem. Try this version (untested).

The main idea, this version saves 50% of random loads/stores spent updating the accumulators. It interleaves the accumulators in memory, uses 128-bit load/add/store instructions, and splits the result back into 2 C# arrays after it consumed all input values.

```
static unsafe void aggregateSse2( double* accumulators, double* a, double* b, byte* dimension, int count )
{
    Debug.Assert( count >= 0 );
    double* aEnd = a + ( count & ( ~1 ) );
    while( a < aEnd )
    {
        // Load accumulator corresponding to the first bucket
        double* accPointer = accumulators + ( 2u * dimension[ 0 ] );
        Vector128<double> acc = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128( accPointer );

        // Load 2 values from each input array.
        // BTW, possible to use AVX and unroll by 4 instead of 2, using GetLow/GetHigh to extract the 16-byte pieces.
        // Gonna save a bit of loads at the cost of more shuffles, might be slightly faster overall.
        Vector128<double> va = Sse2.LoadVector128( a );
        Vector128<double> vb = Sse2.LoadVector128( b );

        // Increment accumulator with the first value of each array, store back to RAM
        acc = Sse2.Add( acc, Sse2.UnpackLow( va, vb ) );
        Sse2.StoreAligned( accPointer, acc );

        // Load accumulator corresponding to the second bucket.
        // Potentially it might be the same pointer, can't load both in advance.
        accPointer = accumulators + ( 2u * dimension[ 1 ] );
        acc = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128( accPointer );
        a += 2;
        b += 2;
        dimension += 2;

        // Increment accumulator with the second value of each array, store back to RAM
        acc = Sse2.Add( acc, Sse2.UnpackHigh( va, vb ) );
        Sse2.StoreAligned( accPointer, acc );
    }

    if( 0 != ( count & 1 ) )
    {
        // The input size was odd number, one item left at these pointers.

        // Load a scalar from first input array into lower lane of a vector
        Vector128<double> vec = Sse2.LoadScalarVector128( a );

        // Load the accumulator corresponding to the bucket
        double* accPointer = accumulators + ( 2u * dimension[ 0 ] );
        Vector128<double> acc = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128( accPointer );

        // Load scalar from second input array into higher lane of that vector
        vec = Sse2.LoadHigh( vec, b );

        // Increment accumulator and store back to RAM
        acc = Sse2.Add( acc, vec );
        Sse2.StoreAligned( accPointer, acc );
    }
}

static unsafe void splitAccumulators( double* values, double* weights, double* accumulators, int numberOfValues )
{
    double* end = accumulators + numberOfValues * 2;
    while( accumulators < end )
    {
        Vector128<double> vec = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128( accumulators );
        accumulators += 2;
        Sse2.StoreScalar( values, vec );
        values++;
        Sse2.StoreHigh( weights, vec );
        weights++;
    }
}

/// <summary>Align pointer by 16 bytes, rounding up.</summary>
[MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
static unsafe void* roundUpBy16( void* pointer )
{
    if( Environment.Is64BitProcess )  // This branch is missing from JIT output BTW, it's free.
    {
        long a = (long)pointer;
        a = ( a + 15L ) & ( -16L );
        return (void*)a;
    }
    else
    {
        int a = (int)pointer;
        a = ( a + 15 ) & ( -16 );
        return (void*)a;
    }
}

[SkipLocalsInit] // Otherwise the runtime gonna zero-initialize the stack allocated buffer, very slowly with `push 0` instructions in a loop.
public static (double[], double[]) AggregateDataSse2( double[] data, double[] weight, byte[] dimension )
{
    Debug.Assert( data.Length == weight.Length && data.Length == dimension.Length );

    const int numberOfValues = 0x100;
    unsafe
    {
        // The buffer is about 4kb RAM, fits in L1D cache.
        // Allocating 2 extra doubles (16 extra bytes) to align the pointer.
        double* accumulators = stackalloc double[ ( numberOfValues * 2 ) + 2 ];
        // Align by 16 bytes
        accumulators = (double*)roundUpBy16( accumulators );
        // Clear accumulators with zeros, let's hope the implementation of that standard library method is good.
        new Span<double>( accumulators, numberOfValues * 2 ).Fill( 0 );

        // Process the input data
        fixed( double* a = data )
        fixed( double* b = weight )
        fixed( byte* dim = dimension )
            aggregateSse2( accumulators, a, b, dim, data.Length );

        // Split the result into 2 arrays
        double[] totalValue = new double[ numberOfValues ];
        double[] totalWeight = new double[ numberOfValues ];
        fixed( double* values = totalValue )
        fixed( double* weights = totalWeight )
            splitAccumulators( values, weights, accumulators, numberOfValues );

        return (totalValue, totalWeight);
    }
}
```

It only uses SSE2 because it doesn’t quite need wider ones, but still, should save non-trivial amount of instructions and RAM transactions compared to your scalar version. I would expect some measurable improvement on all computers.

Comment: Is there no better way to get the C# JIT to zero a 4k buffer?  `rep stosb` would be faster than actual SSE2 stores on modern CPUs, for a buffer that large.

Comment: Anyway yeah, good idea.  Fewer load-buffer and store-buffer entries needed for tracking cache-miss loads to the histogram vs. scalar, and fewer total uops gives OoO exec more room to work its magic.  `movsd` + `movhps` are reasonably cheap, just an extra ALU shuffle uop vs. 2 pure loads.  You might want to add a summary of the strategy: combine the two histograms into pairs of values so you can do the two double adds with one 128-bit operation.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can use `new Span<double>( accumulators, numberOfValues * 2 ).Fill( 0 );` but it compiles into a function call like this: `vxorps xmm1, xmm1, xmm1; call System.Span\`1[[System.Double, System.Private.CoreLib]].Fill(Double)` Don’t know how that standard library method is implemented.

Comment: One might hope it's some equivalent of a decent `memset`, at least taking advantage of ERMSB or AVX on machines where that's good.  I don't have a dev setup where I could single-step into it to check myself.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don’t think it gonna use memset nor ERMSB because it accepts a double argument, but yeah, it might indeed use AVX if available. Updated to use library method instead of manual SSE code.

Comment: Oh, because it it's a function that takes a variable fill pattern that's 64-bit wide.  Yeah, it might use `rep movsq` (which is also fast on most CPUs with ERMSB, even though ERMSB is only officially specified for `rep stosB` and `movsB`).  Anyway, also keeps your source cleaner / simpler and is unlikely to be worse than your manual loop, so that's good.

Comment: @Soonts: I tested and the code works as expected. Just like to say how impressed I am to get such considered answers, with working code so quickly after posting.

Comment: @PeterCordes: when you say "combine the two histograms into pairs of values so you can do the two double adds with one 128-bit operation", do you mean interleave the two data arrays so that I can do a Sse2.LoadVector128 rather than Sse2.LoadScalarVector128 and LoadHigh?

Comment: @Soonts: I'm away from my Ryzen and on my old i7 (Intel Core i7 CPU 860 2.80GHz) The results were 357ms for the naive algo and 290ms for your code. There was no difference coming form the Span.Fill(0) (it was within 1ms and the stdev/error of the tests is ~6ms)

Comment: Two minor questions: (1) I assume there's no significance in the order of the pointer increments in aggregateSse2? Just wondering, in case difference type of operations can get through in the same cycle as a vector operation (please excuse my ignorance in cpu operation!) and (2) are the extra 2 bytes in accumulators simply because of the final increment of the pointer in splitAccumulators before the loop ends?

Comment: @wrgj C# JIT is primitive compared to modern C++ compilers. It rarely reorders instructions (use https://sharplab.io/ for the codez). I’ve tried to place scalar code after loads because I know the CPU likely stall waiting for memory, i.e. these are free cycles. Modern CPUs reorder them as well, but all C++ compilers still do these things on their side (when asked to optimize), I assume these people know what they’re doing.

Comment: About Q2, indeed after the loop ends the `accumulators` points to an invalid address past the end, but that’s OK, I don’t load from there.

Comment: @Soonts: thanks! That's great. The update took 280ms compared to 290ms previously. It certainly feels more vectory. My brain is fried (being 2am), but I might try and interleave the inputs tomorrow, as Peter suggested, so that we don't have to do the unpacking in the middle.
BTW My Q2 was about "Allocating 2 extra doubles (16 extra bytes) to align the pointer." - was the overrun the "alignment" issue? your answer suggested perhaps the invalid address didn't matter, as we don't read it.

Comment: @wrgj: Oh, I was just describing how this code worked, with the histogram itself basically an array of structs.  But yes, if you can arrange your input data to match, that would help, too (if that doesn't make other things worse for SIMD purposes).  For a big histogram, grouping the output is the most important point because it doubles the spatial locality of your scattered stores, but with the buffer being only 4k, it fits in L1d cache so may well bottleneck on front-end throughput, not outstanding cache misses to L2.

Comment: @wrgj I allocate 4kb + 16 bytes, round the pointer up by 16 bytes, and using the 4kb starting from the rounded pointer. The 4kb is always valid ‘coz the rounding step advances the pointer by [ 0 .. 15 ] bytes.

Comment: If you wonder why — `aggregateSse2` accesses that buffer a lot, I think that RAM access is the bottleneck of the complete function. Aligned 16-byte access is guaranteed to only touch 1 cache line (cache lines are 64 bytes, aligned by 64), while unaligned 16-byte access, with almost 25% probability, touches two cache lines. Not too important in this particular use case because 4kb of data fits in L1D, but still, aligned RAM access is slightly faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I understand, thanks. This is ultimately for the local loop within highly parallelised remote computation, so the input sizes will be determined by batch sizes that are optimised wrt the cost of communication b/w processing nodes. On the output side, the bins are then used by being grouped together in different ways to give statistics that fit models. However, the batches need to be re-grouped centrally, so leaving them as an array of structs would actually allow using SIMD for the central aggregation into an overall set of outputs.

Comment: @Soonts: Ah - now I understand the pointer alignment. I hadn't fully appreciated the use of the roundUpBy16 method. Learning something new with every comment! :)

Comment: Soonts and @wrgj: this code may bottleneck on L1d cache accesses, so every cache-line split *would* cost you throughput.  The extra latency can be hidden by OoO exec, but a cache-line split load also occupies the load port again for an extra cycle later.  And for a store, takes two separate L1d writes to modify the two separate lines when the store-buffer entry gets reaches the head of the buffer and commits.

Comment: Although with 2 loads + 1 store per clock on recent microarchitectures (Intel since Haswell if the compiler avoids indexed addressing modes for the store, AMD since Zen 2), there might be enough address-calc work that the front-end is the bottleneck, not back-end load/store ports.  Still, memory-source `movhps`, and memory-source `addpd xmm0, [rdi + rdx]` (if the data is aligned) can sneak memory uops through the front-end micro-fused to ALU uops.  (AVX would actually hurt if the data is aligned on Intel, since an indexed memory addr mode will unlaminate from `vaddpd` but not `addpd`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for the insight, Peter. I hope I understood correctly. Are the cache-line splits related to the possibly unaligned arrays a and b, for both read and write? (btw I'd tested removing the alignment of acc on my old i7 860, and it didn't make a difference.) Is alignment of the large data arrays possible, or is this non-sensicle prior to loading into the cache? Are there any other strategies that could help here (wanting best optimisation on newer architectures)?

Comment: Again, I greatly appreciate the insight. Perhaps the group-by is best avoided completely in the inner loop..? Assuming storage is cheap compared to processing time, my current next line of investigation would be to store a copy of the data for each dimension value I want to group over, and get back to classic vecotrised SIMD summation for each batch.

Comment: @wrgj: Alignment of large allocations is possible in C++.  I don't know how limited C# might be; I don't use it.  It might already be aligning all allocations by 16, especially for 64-bit builds.

Comment: @wrgj: touching lots of memory will lead to cache misses, and probably be worse.  It's very likely that reducing into sums as early as possible is better.  Even if you wanted to make an array for each group, each group would need a current-position pointer which you'd have to index to find where to store that pair of doubles, so you'd just be adding yet another layer of indirection to group into arrays instead of reducing each group into one accumulator.  (As well as leaving a lot of work to do later.)

Answer (score 1):

[Sorry if this should be a comment, not an anwser, but not sure how to format code within a comment]

A version of the answer by Soonts that uses interleaved inputs and outputs is below. However, it ends-up looking equivalent to the Vector2 struct, except using doubles instead of floats. Interestingly, this version is *slower* than the original answer.

Below are the results for the original answer (SSE2), the optimised answer (SSE2a), my "interleaved" version (SSE2i) and the Vector2 (float-based) results (for comparison).

```
|                           Type |             Method | Seed |      Size |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev |
|------------------------------- |------------------- |----- |---------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|
|  AggregatorBenchmarkDoubleSSE2 | AggregateBenchmark |   42 | 100000000 | 288.3 ms | 2.25 ms | 2.10 ms |
| AggregatorBenchmarkDoubleSSE2a | AggregateBenchmark |   42 | 100000000 | 275.6 ms | 5.31 ms | 5.45 ms |
| AggregatorBenchmarkDoubleSSE2i | AggregateBenchmark |   42 | 100000000 | 280.3 ms | 2.69 ms | 2.52 ms |
|     AggregatorBenchmarkVector2 | AggregateBenchmark |   42 | 100000000 | 259.9 ms | 1.48 ms | 1.31 ms |
```

```
        static unsafe void aggregateSse2i(double* accumulators, double* a, byte* dimension, int count)
        {
            Debug.Assert(count >= 0);

            double* aEnd = a + 2 * count;
            while (a < aEnd)
            {
                // Load accumulator corresponding to the first bucket
                double* accPointer = accumulators + (2u * *dimension);
                Vector128<double> acc = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128(accPointer);
                dimension++;

                // Load pair of values from input array.
                // BTW, possible to use AVX and unroll by 4 instead of 2, using GetLow/GetHigh to extract the 16-byte pieces.
                // Gonna save a bit of loads at the cost of more shuffles, might be slightly faster overall.
                Vector128<double> va = Sse2.LoadVector128(a);
                a += 2;

                // Increment accumulator with the first value of each array, store back to RAM
                acc = Sse2.Add(acc, va);
                Sse2.StoreAligned(accPointer, acc);
            }
        }

        static unsafe void splitAccumulators2(double* values, double* accumulators, int numberOfValues)
        {
            double* end = accumulators + numberOfValues * 2;
            while (accumulators < end)
            {
                Vector128<double> vec = Sse2.LoadAlignedVector128(accumulators);
                accumulators += 2;
                Sse2.Store(values, vec);
                values += 2;
            }
        }

        [SkipLocalsInit] // Otherwise the runtime gonna zero-initialize the stack allocated buffer, very slowly with `push 0` instructions in a loop.
        public static double[] AggregateDataSse2i(double[] data, byte[] dimension)
        {
            Debug.Assert(data.Length == 2 * dimension.Length);

            const int numberOfValues = 0x100;
            unsafe
            {
                // The buffer is about 4kb RAM, fits in L1D cache.
                // Allocating 2 extra doubles (16 extra bytes) to align the pointer.
                double* accumulators = stackalloc double[(numberOfValues * 2) + 2];
                // Align by 16 bytes
                accumulators = (double*)roundUpBy16(accumulators);
                // Clear accumulators with zeros, let's hope the implementation of that standard library method is good.
                new Span<double>(accumulators, numberOfValues * 2).Fill(0);

                // Process the input data
                fixed (double* a = data)
                fixed (byte* dim = dimension)
                    aggregateSse2i(accumulators, a, dim, dimension.Length);

                return new Span<double>(accumulators, numberOfValues * 2).ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think instead of `splitAccumulators2` in your code, you can use `return new Span<double>(accumulators, numberOfValues * 2).ToArray();` It doesn‘t split anything, merely an equivalent of `memcpy`

Comment: What's the point of `splitAccumulators2`?  Isn't it just a simple SSE2 memcpy with a `double*` source and `double*` destination?  Is that because you can't return stackalloc buffer?  Why not do a normal allocation in the first place with room for 1 extra double, and *if* it got rounded up then copy in-place (i.e. from roundup to actual buffer start)?  (Hopefully it will already be 16-byte aligned so roundUpBy16 will return its input value, meaning no copy needed). @Soonts.  You'd be returning a buffer with 1 extra double allocated.  (I'm assuming any double alloc will be 8-byte aligned)

Comment: Or don't worry about alignment; it might not save more than an extra copy.  (Except with really unlucky inputs that have a lot of the bucket that splits across a 4k page; that's really slow especially on CPUs before Skylake; IDK about AMD but Intel improved page-split handling a lot.)  Still, it would cost some front-end throughput to not be able to fold loads into `addpd`, if that's even happening in the first place (if you're able to tell C# which loads are definitely aligned)

Comment: @Soonts, PeterCordes : updated the array output - didn't make a significant difference to overall performance.